# Spotify Web API - why is the newly created playlist not populated with chosen songs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spotify

I am currently stuck with a React project on Codecademy - Jamming. It uses Spotify WEB API to create and save a playlist back into a user account.

[image: Jamming Main Page]

The flow is as follows:

1. Enter search term in the search bar,
2. Pressing Search button grabs the temporary access token via the Implicit Grant Flow and returns the search results,
3. The search results are populated in a list of Results,
4. The user selects songs by adding them to the Playlists column,
5. User enters chosen Playlist name and clicks on Save to Spotify,
6. Under the hood, the POST method creates a playlist with the chosen name and returns a unique id (Spotify.savePlaylist(); see below),
7. The unique id is used to populate the playlist with the chosen songs with another POST method.

The problem I am facing is that when I click on Save to Spotify, the playlist is created in my account but empty! To top it all of I get the following message:

[image: 404 Error Message on adding the playlist to Spotify]

I have condensed to standalone code (chopped away from the React App.js) so that the button click is simulated by savePlaylist() function (I managed to reproduce the problem). The Spotify object below holds the methods to get the access token, search for songs, and (what I am interested in) create a playlist and then save the respective tracks.

The module Spotify.js that completes the API actions is as follows:

```js
const clientId = '6acd4fb43b3443c190e390753512049d'//Create a working Spotify Web API project to get the client id
const redirectUri = 'https://www.spotify.com/uk/'; //a redirect uri that matches value in the Spotify WEB API project page
let accessToken;

//below are manual entries for the playlist name and tracks (with unique spotify URI)
const playlistTracks = ["spotify:track:6UaHTPaVvS1rasCTUs64N0", "spotify:track:6bC1z4GVrswBEw0D2pOkbT"];
const playlistName = 'StackOverflow Jams II';

const Spotify = {
    getAccessToken() {
        if (accessToken) {
            return accessToken;
        }

        //check for access token match
        const accessTokenMatch = window.location.href.match(/access_token=([^&]*)/);
        const expiresInMatch = window.location.href.match(/expires_in=([^&]*)/);

        if (accessTokenMatch && expiresInMatch) {
            accessToken = accessTokenMatch[1];
            const expiresIn = Number(expiresInMatch[1]);
            // This clears the parameters, allowing us to grab a new access token when it expires
            window.setTimeout(() => accessToken = '', expiresIn * 1000);
            window.history.pushState('Access Token', null, '/');
            return accessToken;
        } else {
            const accessUrl = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=${clientId}&response_type=token&scope=playlist-modify-public&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}`;
            window.location = accessUrl;
        }
    },

    search(term) {
        const accessToken = Spotify.getAccessToken();
        return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=track&q=${term}`, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
            }
        }).then(response => {
            return response.json();
        }).then(jsonResponse => {
            if (!jsonResponse.tracks) {
                return [];
            }
            return jsonResponse.tracks.items.map(track => ({
                id: track.id,
                name: track.name,
                artist: track.artists[0].name,
                album: track.album.name,
                uri: track.uri
            }));
        })
    },

    savePlaylist(name, trackUris) {
        if (!name || !trackUris.length) {
            return;
        }

        const accessToken = Spotify.getAccessToken();
        const headers = { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` };
        let userId;
        console.log(trackUris);
        console.log(accessToken);

        return fetch('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me', { headers: headers }
        ).then(response => response.json()
        ).then(jsonResponse => {
            userId = jsonResponse.id;
            return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/${userId}/playlists`, {
                headers: headers,
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({ name: name })
            }).then(response => response.json()
            ).then(jsonResponse => {
                const playlistId = jsonResponse.id;
                return fetch(`­https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/${userId}/playlists/${playlistId}/tracks`,
                    {
                        headers: headers,
                        method: 'POST',
                        body: JSON.stringify({ uris: trackUris }) 
                    })
            })
        })
    }
};

function savePlaylist() {
    Spotify.savePlaylist(playlistName, playlistTracks);
  };

savePlaylist();
```

Another minor issue (which may be a symptom) - when I do the search for the first time, the list of tracks is populated and then immediately the page is refreshed. At that point the redirect page has an query string attached with the access token and the expiry time like such:

> http://localhost:3000/#access_token=BQB-F1LdIdZSW5zD7P5IIaxRbbO_jkPZL4RFkDGqzI0IDXEMS6J1P7P4MpqN2ogj-P5oNWfA7Lea2sZlI5g9qTHqNSODlBwI3hNiVjyh45pWujsgsGIaDLyjlxI6cB4PhU72Wvu10Kd_UFfDOaBmlhgmUJ8gpNjCjj6QsIEiJ38&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600

Only when I search for the term again the list of tracks is populated. Could this be related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try - POST https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/{playlist_id}/tracks
instead of - POST https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/{user_id}/playlists/{playlist_id}/tracks
when you are adding tracks to the playlist. see this [blog post](https://developer.spotify.com/community/news/2018/06/12/changes-to-playlist-uris/).